# ORA-01017 error when attempting to connect to Oracle XE from servlet

Tags: java, oracle, servlets

I'm trying to write a servlet application for learning purposes that connects to an Oracle database, queries some data and then prints it to the browser.  Simple!

However, I'm experiencing an *ORA-01017: invalid username/password* when attempting to connect to a locally installed and running version of Oracle XE (19c).  For the sake of testing the connection, I'm connection with the system user.  Here's my code:

```
// http://localhost:8080/demo/
public class DemoServ extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException,IOException {

        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:xe", "system", "SYSTEM");

            con.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The user that I'm using absolutely does exist, and I can connect using SQL Developer without issue.

I would be willing to put this down to my own ignorance of Java, but if I run the following code independently of any servlet, I can connect and execute the sample query!

```
public class DataReader {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523:xe", "system", "SYSTEM");

            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) num FROM dual");

            if (rs.next()) {
                int i = rs.getInt("num"); // get first column returned
                System.out.println("number: " + i);
            }
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've been searching Google for solutions to this, but I have been unable to find a solution, so here I am.

I'm working on Windows 10, using Java 1.8 and Oracle 19c XE.

Any help would be great.  Thanks

Comment: Corrected.  Apologies for the error!

Comment: Hi APC.  I changed the connection string to be as you suggested, but it yields only ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID....  However, I think that this isn't the problem as to get the error that I'm getting above, the connection must have been successful?  Surely you can't get an ORA-01017 without first establishing a successful connection to the DB?

Comment: I'm certain.  I'm able to log in through a non-servlet app or though a DB environment,  This seems to be something related to the servlet :(

Comment: I did notice in the connection that did not work that you capitalized "XE" whereas in the one that works "xe" is lower case.

Comment: That's a typo.  I tried it both ways and it makes no difference in either piece of code.

Comment: [1] Please update your question with the actual stack trace or error (i.e. simply copy and paste it without any filtering or interpretation). [2] Update your question with the version of the Oracle JDBC driver you are using, and also specify your application server and version. [3] [This table lists the driver options](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19c-downloads.html) for 19c, though presumably the driver you are successfully using for the non-servlet code is the one you are using with your servlet as well, right?

Comment: ORA-1017 means you successfully got the database, and that it is up and running. So the most likely issue here is the correctness or the case of either your username or password.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally go this to work, but I cannot explain why.

Oracle 19c is case sensitive, which I knew.  I attempted to disable this, but as it's a depreciated feature, this seemed expeditious.  I altered the password for the system user to be "system", and I can connect successfully.  "SYSTEM" as a password continues to fail.

What strikes me as odd about this is that I'm sure that I tried to use the "system" (lowercase) password in the past.  :(

Anyway, I probably was doing something daft, but at least I'm got over the hump.  Phew!

Thank you to everyone!!